# shm_unlink in linux

Tags: linux, posix, shared-memory

From the man page of `shm_unlink`:

```
 The operation of shm_unlink() is analogous to unlink(2): it removes a
 memory object name, and, once all processes have unmapped the object,
 de-allocates and destroys the contents of the associated memory
 region.  After a successful shm_unlink(), attempts to shm_open()
 an object with the same name fail (unless O_CREAT was specified,
 in which case a new, distinct object is created).
```

The working of this is specified by the sentence

```
it removes a memory object name, and, once all processes have unmapped the object, de-allocates and destroys the contents of the associated region
```

So, does that mean when `shm_unlink` is called, unmapping will be done on all the processes automatically and then the destruction will take place, or will it still exist and as soon as all the processes using this space have unmapped this space (as per their convenience in the future), it will be destroyed?

The above description is the man pages is a bit under descriptive and this can be interpreted in the above two ways, hence my doubt.

Comment: Processes will not get the rug pulled from under their feet.

Comment: @IanAbbott so after all the processes have unmapped it, then only it will be de-allocated right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is here:

> [...] **once all processes have *unmapped* the object**, de-allocates and destroys the contents of the associated region.

The keyword is *unmapped*.

Calling `shm_unlink()` will only affect the calling process, not others that already have the region mapped. If other processes already have that region of shared memory mapped into their address space, it will still be valid for them. This works the same way as it does with files. If a process opens (maps) a file, and a second process deletes it through `unlink`, the first process will still be able to read the file contents from the mapped memory pages.

If the region is shared with multiple processes, the kernel will wait for *all* of them to *unmap* the region and *close* the file descriptor obtained from `shm_open()`, and only then it will de-allocate and destroy the contents of the associated memory region. Even if `shm_unlink()` is called, the kernel must wait before every single process closes their descriptor or terminates (at which point descriptors are automatically closed by the kernel itself).

Comment: So if some process creates a shared memory and that memory is used by multiple other processes which later on call  shm_unlink(), but the first one does not. So will that memory still be active or will it be freed

Comment: @AbhayPatil it will still be active.

Comment: well I have written few codes, which disprove this. Would you have a look at them

Comment: run this first https://pastebin.com/3NiccCRU then https://pastebin.com/0ChchFxa and then https://pastebin.com/RSnyPJ59. The first one creates a shared memory named `OS`, and second and third read from `OS`. Difference is that the 2nd one does not call shm_unlink where as the third one does. And after running the first, you run the first, then you can run second as many times as you would want, as it does not call the unlink. But if you run the third, then you cannot run the second (error). But as you said first is not closed, it still exists, but if that is the case then second one should run

Comment: Have a look and tell if I am mistaken somehow

Comment: @AbhayPatil i've reworded the answer, my bad. See if that's clearer. `shm_unlink()` does not need to be called by each process.

Comment: The processes will also need to `close()` the file descriptor. If a process has `munmap()`d the memory, but still has the open file descriptor from `shm_open()`, then it should be able to `mmap()` it again, even if the region has already been `shm_unlink()`d.

Comment: @IanAbbott you're most definitely right, thank you, edited.